# CameraX imagecapture usecase very slow to succeed

Tags: android, api, kotlin, camera, android-camerax

When i take a photo using CameraX it takes a long time for it capture the image, around a second and a half on my samsung s8, and 5 seconds on a Nexus 4. I already have the capture mode set up to minimize latency, is there anything else that can be done to reduce the latency?

This is the configuration of the usecase

```
private val imageCapture = ImageCapture.Builder()
        .setTargetRotation(Surface.ROTATION_90)
        .setCaptureMode(ImageCapture.CAPTURE_MODE_MINIMIZE_LATENCY)
        .build()
```

Comment: Are you using [`OnImageCapturedCallback`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/core/ImageCapture.OnImageCapturedCallback) or [`OnImageSavedCallback`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/core/ImageCapture.OnImageSavedCallback)? The latter would naturally take more time to complete than the former. Also, did you compare those numbers to capturing images using camera2? If they are way off, it might be worth reporting the issue to the CameraX team.

Comment: Yeah it is on captured, not saved, so it cant be delayed by file writing or anything. I was comparing it to the native camera apps of the phone, which I guess would use camera2, not cameraX, so i'll have a go with that, even if it is a bit of a pain in the arse lol.

Comment: Any answer, idea how to solve it? I also have the same problem on some devices...